# IE9 error: Object doesn't support property or method 'setAttribute'

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9

Function:

```
function disable_hidden_flip_questions(option, value){
    var first_q = document.getElementById('hidden_auto_questions');
    var second_q = document.getElementById('hidden_include_auto');
    var inputs_list = [];
    if(option == 'all'){
        inputs_list.push(first_q.getElementsByTagName("input"));
        inputs_list.push(second_q.getElementsByTagName("input"));
    }else if (option == 'first'){
        inputs_list.push(first_q.getElementsByTagName("input"));
    }else if(option == 'second'){
        inputs_list.push(second_q.getElementsByTagName("input"));
    }

    for (var inputs in inputs_list){
        for(var input in inputs_list[inputs]){
            if(inputs_list[inputs].hasOwnProperty(input) && input != 'length'){
                if(!value){
                    inputs_list[inputs][input].removeAttribute('disabled');
                }else{
                    inputs_list[inputs][input].setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Works perfectly fine in Chrome and Firefox, but in IE9 the console gives me an error on this  line:

```
inputs_list[inputs][input].setAttribute("disabled", "disabled")
```

If I `console.log(inputs_list[inputs][input])` I get this in Chrome:

(The input is being generated by RoR, which is why its `name` and `id` are so long)

```
<input class="radio_buttons optional" id="custom_attributes_trailer_insurance_endorsement_false" name="custom_attributes[trailer_insurance_endorsement]" type="radio" value="false" disabled="disabled">
```

Yay, that's what I wanted (and expected)... But in IE9's console I get this:

```
[object HTMLCollection]
```

Which is completely useless....

So question: Where am I going wrong in IE's exalted view? I know IE9 supports `setAttribute`, so I am assuming it has to do with my `for...in` loops.

**Edit:** So due to comments, the problem could be with the object types (`HTMLCollection` being stored in an `Array`) . If that is indeed the case, how do I go about making everything compatible data types?

Comment: Any reason you aren't using jQuery for this, to avoid this type of cross-browser crud?

Comment: Yes - jQuery has lots of nice things in it and libraries for it, but **this** is the real reason to use it (or a similar cross-browser solution).

Comment: @StephenP do you have a jquery solution for this?

Comment: @ryan - as @vaporbook points out in his answer you get back an `HTMLCollection` from the `getElementsByTagName` - a "native" object the browser implementation gives you, and can therefore vary by browser (though it's not supposed to) -- the main reason to use a library like jQuery is that **it** handles the cross-browser differences like this one. jQuery also gives you more consistent ways to deal with things. In jQuery you might do something along the lines of `$("#hidden_auto_questions input").each(call_my_function);` (Note the CSS style selector)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution in jquery:

```
  $("input[name=trailer_use]").click(function(event){
        if(event.target.id == "trailer_use_yes"){
            $("#hidden_auto_questions").removeClass('hide_auto').addClass('show_auto');
            $("input[name=trailer_insured]").removeAttr("disabled");
            show_trailer_warning(null, "remove");
        }else {
            $("#hidden_auto_questions").removeClass('show_auto').addClass('hide_auto');
            $("input[name=trailer_insured]").attr("disabled", "disabled");
            if($("#hidden_include_auto").hasClass("show_auto")){
                $("#hidden_include_auto").removeClass('show_auto').addClass('hide_auto');
                $('input[name="custom_attributes[trailer_insurance_endorsement]"]').attr("disabled", "disabled");
            }
            show_trailer_warning(null, "disclaimer");
        }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

HTMLCollections are not really arrays, so you may be getting inconsistent results in treating them that way. While all browsers will return an HTMLCollection from getElementsByTagName, there may be crucial differences in how they allow you to treat them. The best approach is to use the DOM methods to access things from the HTMLCollection - so you would use .item(0) to make sure you are referencing a dom node and not the collection itself (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/HTMLCollection). Also, you wouldn't try to manipulate a collection list so if you do use arrays to push data onto, make sure they're separate data and not an HTMLCollection.

Comment: It says in the document that you linked to that I could use square bracket syntax to access the items of an htmlCollection, since at the point its giving me the error `[input]` is just an index of an item, so it would be the same as saying `.item(0)`

Comment: Yes, that's true. When you do "inputs_list.push(first_q.getElementsByTagName("input"));" you're actually pushing an HTMLCollection onto a javascript array object. But you're treating them equally. I'm sorry I can't offer the one change you should make to fix it, just saying it's the mixed handling of those two non-equivalent data constructs that I think is at the root of the problem.